# "puppet agent -t" throws Error: Facter: error while resolving custom facts .../packages_of_interest.rb: undefined local variable or method `package'

Tags: puppet

PROBLEM:
This is the output from running **puppet agent -t**

```
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Loading facts
Error: Facter: error while resolving custom facts in /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/cache/lib/facter/packages_of_interest.rb: undefined local variable or method `package' for main:Object
Did you mean?  packages
Info: Caching catalog for server.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1606329246'
Notice: Applied catalog in 1.40 seconds
```

Comment: I got -2 reputation points for asking this.  Is feedback why out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the subroutine in packages_of_interest.rb, replace package with "matching_package" gets rid of that error.

Adding the the package name to the error message shows which package.  I changed line 57

from

```
      puts "unknown provider passed (#{package[:provider]})"
```

to

```
      puts "unknown provider passed (#{matching_package[:provider]}) for package (#{matching_package[:name]})"
```

The agent replaces this file, so copy the modified file into place once the agent says it updates package_of_interest.rb

This is the error message now:

"unknown provider passed (pip2) for package (javapackages)"

even though pip2 exists on the system

This pip2 message seems like a bug.  Fortunately the agent completes with a warning instead of an error.